# can't see where I am missing ; before statement

Tags: jquery

Iam trying to create a timer using javascript to function the timer and mysqli bound variable `$dbSessionDuration` to retrieve the start time from the db. Issue is that:

- I am receiving a undefined variable as it states I am `missing ; before statement` but I cannot see where the problem is as it is pointing on the same line as the variable itself

How can I fix the error?

```
View source code below:

    (function(){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var time = 
Notice: Undefined variable: dbSessionDurationTime in /web/stud/u0867587/Mobile_app/assessment.php on line 108
null,
      parts = time.split(':'),
      hours = +parts[0],
      minutes = +parts[1],
      seconds = +parts[2],
      span = $('#countdown');

    function correctNum(num) {
      return (num<10)? ("0"+num):num;
    }

    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        seconds--;
        if(seconds == -1) {
            seconds = 59;
            minutes--;

            if(minutes == -1) {
                minutes = 59;
                hours--;

                if(hours==-1) {
                  alert("timer finished");
                  clearInterval(timer);
                  return;
                }
            }
        }
        span.text(correctNum(hours) + ":" + correctNum(minutes) + ":" + correctNum(seconds));
    }, 1000);
  }); 

});
```

Actual code below:

```
(function(){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var time = <?php echo json_encode($dbSessionDurationTime); ?>,
      parts = time.split(':'),
      hours = +parts[0],
      minutes = +parts[1],
      seconds = +parts[2],
      span = $('#countdown');

    function correctNum(num) {
      return (num<10)? ("0"+num):num;
    }

    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        seconds--;
        if(seconds == -1) {
            seconds = 59;
            minutes--;

            if(minutes == -1) {
                minutes = 59;
                hours--;

                if(hours==-1) {
                  alert("timer finished");
                  clearInterval(timer);
                  return;
                }
            }
        }
        span.text(correctNum(hours) + ":" + correctNum(minutes) + ":" + correctNum(seconds));
    }, 1000);
  }); 

});
```

Comment: Maybe you should define `dbSessionDurationTime` in the PHP code

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: dbSessionDurationTime in /web/stud/u0867587/Mobile_app/assessment.php on line 108` doesn't look like valid JavaScript to me.

Comment: Didn't you notice the `Notice: Undefined variable: dbSessionDurationTime in /web/stud/u0867587/Mobile_app/assessment.php on line 108
null,` part? Your `$dbSessionDurationTime` isn't defined.

Comment: The error is on the serverside, in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$dbSessionDurationTime` isn't defined. If you go and define that you should no longer receive this error. This is the PHP and not the Java Script.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a PHP problem not a javascript problem.  Your variable `$dbSessionDurationTime` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The variable $dbSessionDuration is not defined. The error message from the PHP code in the middle of the Javascript code is causing the syntax error.